# How could I include another template on a click with ajax?

Tags: templating, ajax

I am a newbie with ajax and I have to display a template only when clicking on a button. This template is weighing and it will be on all pages, so I want to use ajax.

Someone can help me?

Answer (score 4):

Primarily, this is a Javascript question, not a Craft CMS question. For the Javascript part of this, I would look for general AJAX tutorials or try searching on Stack Overflow.

But rather than downvote this question as being off-topic, here are some things to help on the Craft CMS side of things.

You can create a template to generate a chuck of HTML you want to include in other pages.

For example, if you create a file called:

```
/templates/includes/example.twig
```

You can access that from `http://mysite.com/includes/example` no matter if it's directly in a browser or thru an Ajax request from another page.

If you need to test wether a template is being accessed directly thru a browser or an Ajax request, you can test that with `craft.app.request.isAjax`:

```
{% if craft.app.request.isAjax %}
  Yep
{% else %}
  Nope
{% endif %}
```

If you'd rather have your Javascript deal with JSON data instead of a chuck of HTML code, you have a few options.

You can name a file with the .json extension and file-based routing will automatically serve that URL as the content type 'application/json'.

```
/templates/includes/example.json
```

Or you can use the [Element API plugin](https://github.com/craftcms/element-api). This is a much more performant solution, but require some PHP knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

Quick and dirty (with jQuery, sorry!)

```
<div id="templatePlaceholder"></div>

<script>
   var fragmentUrl = '{{ url('path/to/template') }}';
   $('#templatePlaceholder').load(fragmentUrl);
</script>
```

But read Alex's answer for proper context :)